# Clear params of postgis spheroid

Tags: postgis, spatial

Something is not clear for me about the spheroid in PostGIS. 
We can define a spheroid like this: "SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]"

Okay, but what is the 298.257222101 number mean? First I thought this is the continued value of the radius of Earth (6378137,298.257222101) but if I change it, it caused bigger changes than I change, for example the last digit of 6378137.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the [**inverse flattening**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattening), 1/*f*. See [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS_84).

If you take the GRS 80 coefficients for semimajor and semiminor axes, *a* and *b*, you can see how it relates to 1/*f*:

```
a = 6378137.0
b = a * (1 - f) ≈ 6356752.314140
1/f = a / (a - b) ≈ 298.257222101
```